# How can I remove the comma at the end of the output?

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to split the numbers and the words. The code is completed, and it works. I'm just wondering how to remove the comma at the end of the output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
vector<string> split(string targer, string delimiter);
int main()
{
   string s, delimiter;
   vector<string> tokens;
   cout << "Enter string to spilt:" << endl;
   getline (cin,s);
   cout << "Enter delimiter string:" << endl;
   getline (cin,delimiter);

   tokens = split(s, delimiter);
   cout << "The substrings are: ";
   for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
   {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"" << "," << " ";

   }
   cout<<endl;
   return 0;
}
vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter){
 stringstream ss(target);
 string item;
 vector<string> tokens;
 while (getline(ss, item, delimiter.at(0))) {
    tokens.push_back(item);
 }
 return tokens;
}
```

Comment: As a general recommendation: If you expect a long vector to be returned by a function, it's better to make the function a void and have a non-const vector reference as a parameter of the function where you store your results. That way you might save your program unnecessary copies there and back.

Comment: @phil13131 It would be fine if write `vector<string> tokens = split(s, delimiter);` to make RVO effective.

Comment: @phil13131 Copy elision is a thing. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @JesperJuhl That is true indeed. In this simple scenario the obvious right choice, thanks for the addition! I just wanted to mention it for a general case, as it is sometimes not possible to call the function at the point of declaration.

Comment: @phil13131 There is move semantics. If code is written properly no copy will be executed. Using return parameters in functions is ambiguous (you look at function declaration and have no way to be sure is this is return parameter or not), so it should be used with great care: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `if` condition for it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
{
    if (i != 0) cout << "," << " ";
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"";
}
```

or

```
string dlmtr = "";
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
{
    cout << dlmtr << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"";
    dlmtr = ", ";
}
```

Comment: Downside of this approach is that you're applying a test in every iteration even though you know it's only going to happen once, at the boundary.

Comment: @beldaz That's why the 2nd candidate exists.

Comment: Meh. Still looks like you're setting dlmtr every iteration, even though it never changes after the first iteration. Not so different to the explicit test. But it's just a personal style thing. Yours is a perfectly good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try outputting the last `cout` statement outside the `for` loop like so:

PREVIOUS CODE:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
   {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"" << "," << " ";

   }
cout<<endl;
```

NEW CODE:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size() - 1; i++)
   {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"" << "," << " ";

   }
if (tokens.size() != 0)
    cout << "\"" << tokens[tokens.size() - 1] << "\"";
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: It'll be dangerous if `tokens.size()` == 0.

Comment: @songyuanyao Thanks for the observation. I changed it.

Comment: This is a neater approach than the others. I'd even suggest doing it the other way round, doing the special case of the first element, then iterating through subsequent elements for which the value of preceded by a comma.

Comment: @beldaz Disagree, unless you mean writing same code twice is neater. Keep [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: @songyuanyao I think your attempt to keep things DRY is approaching premature optimisation. But this is hardly mission critical code so no big deal. Personally I prefer semantically different steps to be visibly distinct. If you've got identical code in both steps I'd just factor out the common code (it'll likely get inlined back later).

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
{
     if (i > 0)
          cout << ", ";
     cout << '"' << tokens[i] << '"';
}
```

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajaj -  "Please explain your code" - since this is obviously an excersize, I leave as an excersize for the OP to understand my code. It is pretty easy. "Would this not print a comma after the last token[token.size() - 1]?" - no, it wouldn't.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I did not realise it would not leave a comma in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t i = 0;

for(; i < tokens.size() - 1; i++) {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"" << "," << " ";
}

if (tokens.size() - 1 >= 0 ) {
    cout << "\"" << tokens[i] << "\"";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using backspace `\b`
 escape character?

Just outside of the for loop, add this ASCII character.

Comment: Hard to do if the output has already been delivered to the client. The backspace winds up chasing the unwanted character, and the receiver may have processed the incorrect message before the backspace catches up. Eg. serial port or network socket.